# Subrings of complex numbers field with a property

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory

We are looking for all subrings $R\neq 0$ of the field $(\mathbb{C},+,.)$ with the property that for every $x,y\in R$ there exists $z\in R$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$, and if $z=0$, then $x=y=0$.

It is obvious that $i\notin R$, and  $\mathbb{R}$ enjoys the property but not $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Can one characterize all such subrings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_field

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116716/is-the-pythagorean-closure-of-mathbb-q-equal-to-the-field-of-constructible-nu